# Tkinter Creations

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Can anyone point me toward some of the more visually intricate / complicated examples of what can be done with Tkinter?  Canvas based widgets and OpenGL please.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of "best" and "ceiling"? Elaborate `Canvas`-based widgets, integration with matplotlib or OpenGL? Most of the demos/examples out there seem to be pretty basic.

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ and http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/

Comment: @Roland I mean the most intricate designs that have been created visually.  A quick search for "Best of Web Development 2018" or the like yields many top 10 style results.  I am just trying to decide whether the limitations of library aesthetically will come before the limits of what I am trying to achieve.  I learned yesterday that I cannot makes frames transparent, which already hinders the design I have in mind since I was hoping for a partial transparency, so maybe I need to be looking for some other tool for the job, hence my desire to see what people have come up with using Tkinter.

Comment: @Bryan, that clearly isn't true since there has been an answer given in which I can see some examples.  Please try to be helpful when answering questions, or just don't.

Comment: I also learned yesterday that (at least simple) animations can be created in Tkinter.  I just want to have an idea of the limitations before I continue down the road of learning it, or switch now to a more powerful tool.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @OddlySpecific: I think there's a big difference between "examples" and "examples of the best that Tkinter can do". There are many examples out there, but no site that lists the best that tkinter can do, and no tkinter competitions.

Comment: @BryanOakley if you have a suggestion on how to word the question in a way that leads people to understand that I am looking for things more complicated than "This is a box, click ok and the box will close, click cancel and the box will stay open" then I would be happy to edit the context of my question to get those answers.  The way I worded it was the one I was able to come up with.  I have found plenty of examples of a gray box with gray buttons, but I am looking for something more visually intricate.

Comment: I think your question was very clear, and which is why I answered "no". There simply are no sites that I know of specifically for showcasing tkinter applications. It's odd that you claim you want to see something more than just "this is a box...", yet accepted an answer that showed not much more than that.

Comment: I selected that answer because it at least lead me to examples, and I've been offered no alternative answers.  Those examples are more intricate than what I've found so far.

Comment: @BryanOakley however, you are right, with the rewording of the question I suppose that answer does not complete the criteria.  But truly I am not here to try and prove I am right about something, I am trying to get examples is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple I think might be interesting;

- [Py in my eye](https://pyinmyeye.blogspot.com/)
- [tkDocs](https://tkdocs.com/index.html)

There are a couple of things to keep in mind;

- Tk is over 25 years old. On X11 it predates things like Freetype. It is still evolving though.
- Tk is cross-platform. This implies that it generally cannot use the latest and greatest platform-specific tricks. It has to work with all the platforms it supports.
- "Theming" and "skins" are *relatively new* in GUI toolkits. Some of them (GTK+ comes to mind) had to be re-designed internally to be able to use themes. Tk acquired theming support relatively recently.
- Things like transparency are platform dependent, making it difficult for a toolkit to support it on all platforms. E.g. on X11 it requires the rendering extension.
- It you want to do really graphics intensive stuff, a GUI toolkit might not be the best tool for the job. A games toolkit like [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news) or OpenGL interface might suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

There were samples in python-2.7.15 that could represent what you are looking for:

On my Linux install they are located in /usr/doc/python-2.7.15/Demo/tkinter

if you have python3 only, you could maybe look for an older version to download and install, see if the documents get installed.

Comment: Found some in my 3.7 installation in \Python37-32\Tools\demo
Thanks for the lead.